# Фильтрация меток одной кнопкой, в зависимости от этажа

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Суть вопроса передана в видео: https://vk.com/im?sel=20273204&z=video20273204_456239197%2Fb1c6d19067110a581c

Так происходит фильтрация в меню:

```
function setupSidebar () {
var layoutClass = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    "<div class=sidebar>"+
        "<div class='show_icon click' id=show_Home></div>"+
    "</div>", {
        build: function () {
            layoutClass.superclass.build.call(this);
            this._setupButtons();
        },

        clear: function () {
            this._teardownButtons();
            layoutClass.superclass.clear.call(this);
        },

        _setupButtons: function () {
            this._listeners = {};
            this._filters = [];
            this._setupButton(document.getElementById('show_Home), 'Home');
        },

       _setupButton: function (element, key) {
            this._filters.push(key);
            var group = ymaps.domEvent.manager.group(element);
            group.add('click', function () {

                var index = this._filters.indexOf(key);
                if (index == -1) {
                    this._filters.push(key);
                } else {
                    this._filters.splice(index, 1);
                }

                objectManager.setFilter(
                    'properties.type == "' + this._filters.join('" || properties.type == "') + '"'
                );
            }, this);
            this._listeners[key] = group;
        },

        _teardownButtons: function () {
            for (var key in this._listeners) {
                if (this._listeners.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    this._listeners[key].removeAll();

                }
            }
            this._listeners = {};
        }
    }
);
ymaps.layout.storage.add('game#sidebatLayout', layoutClass);
```

А так, по этажам

```
`var typeSelector = new ymaps.control.TypeSelector({

     data: {
            content: 'Этажи'
        },
        options: {

        size: 'auto'
        },
        mapTypes: [
            'my#mapTypeA',
            'my#mapTypeB',
            'my#mapTypeC',
            'my#mapTypeD',
            'my#mapTypeE'
        ]
    });

typeSelector.options.set('position', {top: 10, right: 170});
typeSelector.options.set('fixTitle', false);

map.controls.add(typeSelector)

    typeSelector.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
        var listBoxLevelItems = e.get('target');
        var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, typeSelector.state.get('filters'));
        filters[listBoxLevelItems.data.get('content')] = listBoxLevelItems.isSelected();
        typeSelector.state.set('filters', filters);
    });

    var filterMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(typeSelector.state);
    filterMonitor.add('filters', function(filters) {

        objectManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction(filters));
        objectKabinetsManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction(filters));
    });

    function getFilterFunction(categories){
        return function(obj){
            var content = obj.properties.level;
            return categories[content]
        }
    }`
```

Оба кода не мои, первый Всеволода Шмырова с конференции. Второй из песочницы

Вопрос в том, как передать другому фильтру номер этажа. на котором находимся?

Comment: Создайте переменную, которая всегда будет иметь значение равное текущему выбранному этажу, и меняйте её значение при смене этажа.

Comment: немного не понимаю, как это можно реализовать. мне нужна переменная равная map. getType() Потом мне нужно ее добавить к значению "Home" в  _setupButton, и потом, к фильтру по типам, добавить фильтр по этажам? Как это сделать?